# Infinispan Cluster doesn't recover and rejoin cluster after network issue

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I am using jgroups-4.0.12.Final.jar with infinispan-core-9.3.0.

And facing an issue where the cluster view is not recovering after network failure.

Cluster A has single node.

Cluster B - 3 nodes
Node X - coordinator
Node Y and Node Z are up.

Initial VIEW {A, X} at cluster A node and Cluster B node X.
Cluster B node has tcp connection established with Node X in Cluster B.

Now when there is network glitch experienced by Node X, which last for 2 mins, following is happening.

1. Cluster A - suspects Node X for configured 45 sec and then removes it from the VIEW.

TCP connection is removed.
Cluster A VIEW {A}
Cluster B Node X VIEW {X}

2. Node Y in Cluster B becomes coordinator and sends JOIN_REQ to Cluster A node.

Node Y established tcp connection with Cluster A node.

Cluster A VIEW {A, Y}
Cluster B Node Y VIEW {A, Y}

3. But as soon as Node X network gets connected, Node Y relinquishes its coordinator role and sends LEAVE_REQ to Cluster A node. The tcp connection is dropped.
   Cluster A VIEW {A}
   Cluster B Node X VIEW {X}

Now here I am expecting the Node X to send JOIN_REQ to Cluster A or may be a merge? But its not happening unless I restart the node X.
And the I see node Y becoming permanent coordinator.

Intracluster cluster B config

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd">
   <TCP bind_addr="X" bind_port="7900" enable_diagnostics="false" max_bundle_size="64K" port_range="1" recv_buf_size="20M" send_buf_size="640K" sock_conn_timeout="300" thread_naming_pattern="pl" thread_pool.enabled="true" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000" thread_pool.max_threads="60" thread_pool.min_threads="2"/>

  
   <TCPPING ergonomics="false" initial_hosts="X[8700],Y[8700],Z[8700]" port_range="1"/>

   <MERGE3 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000"/>
   <FD_SOCK port_range="1" start_port="8702"/>
   <FD max_tries="3" timeout="15000"/>
   <VERIFY_SUSPECT num_msgs="2" timeout="10000"/>

   <pbcast.NAKACK2 discard_delivered_msgs="false" max_rebroadcast_timeout="3000" use_mcast_xmit="false" xmit_interval="1000" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="10000" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="10000" xmit_table_num_rows="100"/>

  <UNICAST3 conn_expiry_timeout="0" xmit_interval="500" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="10000" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="10000" xmit_table_num_rows="20"/>

   <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="1M" stability_delay="1000"/>
   <pbcast.GMS join_timeout="7000" print_local_addr="false" view_bundling="true"/>

   
    <UFC max_credits="2m" min_threshold="0.40"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2m" min_threshold="0.40"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="30k"/>

   <RSVP ack_on_delivery="false" resend_interval="500" timeout="60000"/>
<relay.RELAY2 async_relay_creation="true" config="/usr/local/symplified/etc/xsite_relay2_config.xml" relay_multicasts="false" site="EG"/>
</config>
```

Cluster config

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd">
    <TCP bind_addr="X node IP" bind_port="8700" enable_diagnostics="false" max_bundle_size="64000" port_range="1" recv_buf_size="20000000" send_buf_size="640000" sock_conn_timeout="300" thread_pool.enabled="true" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000" thread_pool.max_threads="8" thread_pool.min_threads="1"/>

    <TCPPING ergonomics="false" initial_hosts="A[8700],X[8700],Y[8700],Z[8700]" port_range="0"/>

  
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD max_tries="3" timeout="15000"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT num_msgs="3" timeout="10000"/>

    <pbcast.NAKACK2 discard_delivered_msgs="true" max_rebroadcast_timeout="3000" use_mcast_xmit="false" xmit_interval="1000" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="10000" xmit_table_num_rows="100"/>
    <UNICAST3 conn_expiry_timeout="0" xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000" xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000" xmit_table_num_rows="100"/>

    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="8m" stability_delay="1000"/>
    <pbcast.GMS join_timeout="3000" print_local_addr="false"/>

    <UFC max_credits="4M" min_threshold="0.1"/>
    <MFC max_credits="4M" min_threshold="0.2"/>

    <FRAG2 frag_size="60000"/>
    <RSVP ack_on_delivery="false" resend_interval="500" timeout="60000"/>
</config>
```

Am I missing any config which can help node X resyncs its view and send JOIN_REG again to Cluster A node? Or let Node Y become permanent coordinator and have the tcp connection with Cluster A node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<MERGE3 .../>` is missing from the second configuration which can explain why node `X` isn't reconnecting again.

Comment: Ahh .. sorry .. my bad . While creating this post i missed to copy the configuration . Updated the config in query. Both the config have <MERGE3 .../>

Comment: I'm afraid I need some logs to debug the problem (or a reproducer). MERGE3 should kick in periodically to find and fix this situation. Note that those are old versions of Infinispan and JGroups and, if it is a bug, it'll be fixed in the latest stable versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out . I checked again the configuration and it was not having <MERGE 3 .../> configuration in XML . After adding the element, the issue is resolved . 
 Thanks.